# is there any cleaner way to apply function to list

Tags: python

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

def addOne(a): 
    return a+1
```

`addOne(A)` doesn't work, obviously because I don't want A+1,

I want to get `[[[2,3,4]],[5,6,7]]`

`[addone(x) for x in y for y in A]` doesn't work either, I think list comprehensions doesn't work that way.

note, addOne is just a placeholder for a more complicated function

Comment: `list(map(func, A))` or `[func(x) for x in A]` I don't know why you thought you had to do `for x in y for y in A`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> nums = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> def add_one(a):
...     return a + 1
... 
>>> [list(map(add_one, sublist)) for sublist in nums]
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
>>> [[add_one(num) for num in sublist] for sublist in nums]
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: or just: [x+1 for x in A]

Comment: @MitchWheat Maybe... but OP might just be using the "add_one" function as a placeholder to put a different function in later.

Comment: True................

Comment: @MitchWheat the duplicate you linked to doesn't really apply as per OPs latest edit: "note, addOne is just a placeholder for a more complicated function"

Comment: I can't help it if the poster chnages question! It's completely different.!

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes, I see the examples have now changed from 1D to 2D but the question/title has always been the same: "is there any cleaner way to apply function to list". The duplicate you linked to does not apply a function to a list.